# How to break the chain of Task when an exception occurs?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, multitasking

I create the chain of the works. They are to work inside of my additional thread. I use the `Task` for this purpose. Also, I want to break the chain's work if any exception occurred and throw it in the calling thread. But I see my chain wasn't broken and the `act2` with `act3` was completed too.

How can I fix it?

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bushman.Sandbox.Threads {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.Title = "Custom thread";

            try {
                // First work
                Action act1 = () => {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                        // I throw the exeption here
                        if (i == 3) throw new Exception("Oops!!!");

                        Console.WriteLine("Do first work");
                    }
                };

                // Second work
                Action act2 = () => {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("  Do second work");
                };

                // Third work
                Func<int> act3 = () => {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("    Do third work");
                    return 12345;
                };

                Task task = new Task(act1);

                // Build the chain of the works
                var awaiter = task.ContinueWith(_ => act2(),
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
                    .ContinueWith(_ => act3(),
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
                    .GetAwaiter();

                Console.WriteLine("Work started...");

                // launch the chain
                task.Start();

                // Here I get some result
                int result = awaiter.GetResult(); // 12345

                if (task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted) {
                    throw task.Exception.InnerException;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The result: {0}",
                    result.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `async/await`? You don't need `Task.Start` or direct access to the awaiter either. Furthermore, if you want to use `ContinueWith` you *need* access to the task to check for exceptions, eg - `ContinueWith(t => if (t.Faulted) {..} else act3();)`

Comment: I learn to work with the threads\tasks through a book. I still didn't read about `async/await`.

Comment: I suggest you check the documentation examples on how to properly use eg, ContinueWith and TasFactory.StartNew or Task.Run if you don't want to use `async/await`. Also check what Task.Result and Task.Wait() do - they *do* throw if a task is faulted. Your code is far too complicated and tries to expose implementation internals that it just doesn't need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the NotOnFaulted Task Continuation Option.

Since [TaskContinuationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) is decorated with the Flags attribute, you can combine NotFaulted with other options.

```
 var awaiter = task.ContinueWith(_ => act2(),
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
                .ContinueWith(_ => act3(),
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
                .GetAwaiter();
```

Even if you are using the **async/await** keywords, this approach is still valid (but you get rid of *GetAwaiter* call)

Comment: Thank you. At this case `act2` wasn't launched, but `act3` was launched still.

Comment: Oh... If I add `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled` together with `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted` then it work like I expected. Thank you!

Comment: Try the AttachedToParent flag.

Comment: Please notice that if you use the ExecuteSynchronously flag, you are not really using the real power of Tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The code is trying to use tasks in an unconventional way, almost as if they were threads. They aren't - tasks are a job that will get scheduled to run on a threadpool thread, not the thread itself. Calling `Task.Start` won't execute anything, it will *schedule* its delegate to run on a thread. That's why tasks are never created using the constructor.

The easiest way to start and coordinate tasks is to use Task.Run and `async/await`, eg:

```
public static async Task<int> MyMethodAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>act1());
        await Task.Run(()=>act2());
        var result=await Task.Run(()=>act3());
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
           //Do something
    }
}
```

You can't use `async/await` on a console application's Main function, so you'll have to call the method in the following way:

```
var result=MyMethodAsync().Result;
```

Calling `.Wait()` or `.Result` on a task rethrows any exceptions raised inside it.

*Without* `async/await`, you'd need to use `ContinueWith` and actually check the result of the previous task. If you simply want to stop processing, you can pass TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted :

```
var result = Task.Run(()=>act1())
                 .ContinueWith( t1=>act2(),TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
                 .ContinueWith( t2=>act3(),TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
                 .Result;
```

You don't need to get explicit access to the awaiter. The final call to `.Result` will either return the integer result or throw an `AggregateException` if one of the previous tasks faulted

Comment: Using the ContinueWith method is "conventional". I agree with you that async/await are cleaner and easier to maintain, but there is nothing wrong to use Start/GetAwaiter/GetResults. In the end, async/await are just syntactic sugar over such methods.

Comment: @MatteoMarciano-MSCP these methods were only necessary with WinRT, which didn't have tasks. No other runtime needs them. As for why it's wrong to use them, the code's complexity is obvious. The code ends up a lot more complex for no benefit. The only place you'll find `Task.Start` is in SO questions

Comment: Continuations are still used and still needed in some situations. About WinRT not supporting Tasks, it's not entirely true. Maybe you are talking about WinRT components.

Comment: I didn't say that continuations aren't used. I said that awaiters aren't used